# Generating uuid that does not exist in table

Tags: postgresql, uuid

I need to generate an uuid that does not exist in a certain column in a table. I found a function `gen_random_uuid()`. Is there some way in the loop to check if such an uuid exists and replace it if it does?

```
CREATE TABLE x (id UUID PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)

INSERT INTO x VALUES (
gen_random_uuid(),   // Need to check if uuid not exist in id column
'some name'
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more uuid than atoms in the universe. So the chance of randomly picking the same twice is virtually zero. That is exactly the point of uuid, you do not have to check that they are unique. You just assume they are by construction.

Comment: I understand that the probability of repetition tends to zero, but it is still not zero. I would like to be sure that nothing is faulty)

But okay, I will assume that they will always be unique. Thank you!